Print Pdf from Html in Nodejs API
I am trying to set up a NodeJs API, for printing pdf using several templates.
My problem is that 2 of those templates use Html customized by our users.
I am trying phantomJS, because so far it was the only I managed to get to work.
However, the logo image is giving me a hard time to insert in the header.
So, I need to know if there is any better aproach or if is possible to make it work.
Since every user has a different logo, I need to insert different images when printing.
What I have tried so far:
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import Handlebars from 'handlebars';
import pdf, { CreateOptions } from 'html-pdf';
import { encode } from 'node-base64-image';
var path = require('path');

export const generate = async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  const dateTime = new Date().toISOString().replace('T', ' ').replace(':', '-').substr(0, 19).replace(' ', '_').replace(':', '-');
  const {
    name, email, cpfCnpj, documentName = 'textAuthDoc', docTitle = 'Documento de Autorização',
    accountingOfficeId = "5cc6adc6-were-1542-etr-acbf0030000"
  } = req.body;

  const logoPath = await getLogoAsync('https://logowebpath', accountingOfficeId);
  const logoImage = await getLogo('https://logowebpath');

  var htmlHeader = readFileSync(`src\\_templates\\header.html`, 'utf8')
  var templateHeader = Handlebars.compile((htmlHeader));
  var dataHeader = {"headerTitle": docTitle, "logoImage": logoPath};
  var resultHeader = templateHeader(dataHeader);

  var options: CreateOptions = {
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    border: {
      // top: '70',
      right: '25',
      bottom: '60',
      left: '25'
    },
    header: {
      height: "70",
      contents: resultHeader
    },
    footer: {
      height: '60'
    },
    zoomFactor: '1.5',
    type: 'pdf'
  };

  var htmlTemplate = await readFileSync(`src/_templates/${documentName}.html`, 'utf8') + `</html>`;

  var templateHandled = Handlebars.compile((htmlTemplate));

  var data = { "Cliente": name, "email": email, "CPFCNPJ_Cliente": cpfCnpj, "logoImage": logoImage};
  var result = `<div style='display:none'><img src='${logoImage}' /></div>`.concat(templateHandled(data));


  pdf.create(result, options).toStream(function(err, stream) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        res.set('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
        stream.pipe(res)
    }
  });

}


It prints the customized html nicely in the body of Pdf file, but the header have no image.
I tried these two functions to download the images. They work, but I can't manage to insert in the resulting PDF.

  async function getLogo(logoPath: string): Promise<string> {
  // encoding a jpg to base64
  const url = logoPath;
  const options = {
    string: true,
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "my-app"
    }
  };

  // writing to file named 'example.jpg'
  const image = await encode(url, options);
  // await decode(image, { fname: 'example', ext: 'jpg' });


    return image.toString('base64');
  }

async function getLogoAsync(imageUrl: string, accountingOfficeId: string, ) {
  const https = require('https');
  const fs = require('fs');

  var imagePath = path.join(__dirname + '/../../../_images', `${accountingOfficeId}.${'png'}`);
  const imageName = imagePath;

  const file = await fs.createWriteStream(imageName);

  await https.get(imageUrl, (response: { pipe: (arg0: any) => void; }) => {

    console.log(`Image downloaded as ${response.pipe}`);

    response.pipe(file);

    file.on('finish', () => {
      file.close();
      // // console.log(`Image downloaded as ${imageName}`);
    });
  }).on('error', (err: { message: any; }) => {
    fs.unlink(imageName);
    console.error(`Error downloading image: ${err.message}`);
  });

  return imageName;
}

Sorry for the messy code, I am doing tons of tests.
I am using Nodejs 20.15.0
Here is the html header:


  <div id="container" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto">
    <div id="inner" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto">
      <div style="float: left; height: 104px; display: flex">
        <span
          style="
            display: inline-block;
            align-self: flex-end;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: #00f;
          "
          >{{headerTitle}}</span
        >
      </div>
      <div style="float: right; height: 104px; text-align: bottom">
        <img
          src="{{logoImage}}"
          alt="logo"
          width="auto"
          height="104"
          style="background-color: antiquewhite;"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


